# query has no destination for result data in POSTGRESQL for stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

having a slight issue here, trying to call this function, but getting this error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

used perform but that is not what I need. I don't understand the error message, do i need to return a table or something?

```
create or replace procedure myProc(colkey varchar, colvalue varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
old varchar(250);
keyId bigint;

begin

select @keyid= id
from conkey
where conkey.key like colkey
limit 1;



if not exists (select * from ConValu where conkeyId= @keyid and appId is null) THEN 

else 

select @old_value_for_update = value 
from ConValu
where conkeyId= @conkeyId and appId is null
limit 1; 

update ConValu  set Value = colvalue where ConkeyId= @conkeyID and appId is null;

end if;

end; $$
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) parameters are not prefixed with `@` in PL/pgSQL. When you run a query you need to [store the result somewhere](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+"query+has+no+destination+for+result+data")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to try to use T-SQL syntax in PL/pgSQL. But in PL/pgSQL variables aren't and cannot be prefixed with `@`. But you can and should prefix them with an underscore (`_`) (or some other valid prefix) to avoid name clashes with column names which can result in pretty hard to find errors.

Either way they need to be declared in the `DECLARE` block. You also missed that for that variables now beginning with `@`.

And they cannot be filled in a query with the `<variable name> = <column expression>` syntax.

You need to either use `SELECT ... INTO ...` or a subquery and an assignment.

Like

```
SELECT value 
       INTO _old_value_for_update
       FROM convalu
       WHERE conkeyid = _conkeyid
             AND appid IS NULL
       LIMIT 1;
```

or:

```
_old_value_for_update := (SELECT value 
                                 FROM convalu
                                 WHERE conkeyid = _conkeyid
                                       AND appid IS NULL
                                 LIMIT 1);
```

Oh and one thing I already forgot: If you use `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` the rows chosen are expected to be random. I couldn't introduce an `ORDER BY` because I don't know what could make sense in your case.